# Cannot use .some() with array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to check wether my array of objects contains an atribute with a specified value. For this I thought of using `array.some()`, instead of a foreach loop. However I keep getting an error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '(element: ListaDetalhePendenciaAprovacao) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: ListaDetalhePendenciaAprovacao, index: number, array: ListaDetalhePendenciaAprovacao[]) => boolean'.
> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

The code is as follows:

```
   let existeApr = this.pendenciasList.some(element =>{
      !isUndefined(element.isSelected) && element.isSelected
    })

   let existeRej = this.pendenciasList.some(element =>{
      !isUndefined(element.isSelected) && element.isSelected
    })
```

I've also been hving the same issue with array.findIndex().
I apologize for the atributes being in my native language, I don't think it should be an issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The callbacks of your `some` don't return anything. Use `return !isUndefined(...) && ...`  or  .some(element => !isUndefined(...) && )`

Comment: @derpirscher Thanks! That was pretty much it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because of the curly braces in the callback that you pass to `some`. If you open the curly braces, then you need to return a boolean value from it:

```
let existeApr = this.pendenciasList.some(element =>{
  return !isUndefined(element.isSelected) && element.isSelected
})
```

But for a one liner like yours, you should drop the curly braces altogether and go with something like this:

```
let existeApr = this.pendenciasList.some(element =>
  !isUndefined(element.isSelected) && element.isSelected)
```

Comment: Thanks Octavtian! That was it. Thanks for the help! I'll accept the answer in a few minutes